# How does google's spider find files hidden behind login walls?

Tags: security, authentication, web-crawler

This page:

`http://netfs.dev.itcs.co.uk/downloads`

is hidden behind a login wall.

When I use:

`site:http://netfs.dev.itcs.co.uk/downloads *.pdf`

as my google search string, google seems to be able to return an extensive list of pdf files that live within that URL directory.

My first thought was that these files were being linked to from another site, yet searching for a specific pdf:

`netfs.dev.itcs.co.uk/downloads/BTFP%20FAQs.pdf`

only returns 1 result (from `netfs.dev.itcs.co.uk`). I'm totally perplexed - how is google seemingly able to circumvent the login wall?

I tried spoofing my user-agent to that of the google-bots and that also didn't work. Obviously they could figure out its a spoof, but given that they don't even have HTTPS on their login page, I find it hard to believe they're doing anything complicated....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The pdf is propably embeded in some publicly accessible page. If you run a spider on the site you'll find hundreds of files in the /downloads directory.

Comment: Thanks for this @t.m.adam. I would have thought that if this were the case, I would get multiple results when I search for a specific pdf. One on netfs.dev.itcs.co.uk, and one on the publicly accessible page?